# Is there a Magento event called on all pageviews but not on redirect?

Tags: magento

I've played with a number of the controller events but haven't been able to identify one that is called when redirect isn't. Also looked at cms_pageview, but theres no equivalent for all other page types. Is there an event called later in the stack that redirect doesn't trigger or a method for checking if a redirect was requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *a lot* of dynamic and generic events which you can consume; best to describe your needs.

Provided that the request is dispatched through the Front Controller, the response is sent in `dispatch()`, and that response may include a redirect header; you should be able to read the response object headers or status code to see if a redirect has been set.

```
if (Mage::app()->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
    //this will work assuming that the status code has been set
}
```

For more see `Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract`.

Comment: Follow up question: is there a flag to determine whether the request is for an admin page? Thanks!

Comment: There are a number of ways to determine admin context. For `controller_action_predispatch` and all events dispatched after, you can configure observer under `adminhtml` area (xpath). You can also check the running store in your observer code `Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()`; however, this store isn't set until *just* before the `adminhtml` area is loaded, so they effectively accomplish the same thing.